# JavaFX FXCollection.observableArrayList(); not found

Tags: java, sql, javafx

For some reason the second FXCollections.observableArrayList() is not working. Any ideas why this might be? The first one, which is identical, works fine.

```
public void buildData()
{
    data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM FRACKEN";
    ResultSet rs = c.createStatement().executeQuery(query);
    Callback param;
    try {
        for(int i = 0; i < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++)
        {
            final int j = i;
            TableColumn col = new TableColumn(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i+1));
            col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String>,ObservableValue<String>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {
                    return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());
                }
            });
            tableview.getColumns().addAll(col);
        }
        while(rs.next())
        {
            ObservableList<String> row = new FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            for(int i = 0; i <= rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();i++)
            {
                row.add(rs.getString(i));
            }
            data.add(row);


        }
        tableview.setItems(data);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
}
```

Comment: `new`?  Extra letters to satisfy SO.

Comment: wow, so simple. Silly me haha. Thanks!